# Is there any way to make ftp connection from expo-react-native app?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm writing a expo-react-native mobile app, which should send and recive data via ftp.
I found only one library for doing that: 'react-native-ftp', but it doesn't seem to work with expo: when I import this, the value of FTP is undefined.
Is there any ways to make ftp connections from expo-react-native app?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.